# IE Edge form submission Issue with rgb colors

Tags: forms, rgb, microsoft-edge

Hello Dears Stack Overflow, Great site, I have been able to solve many questions with your guidance.

Issue:

Working with a php website script I be having issues when atempt to submit a form to database whit a field DESCRIPTION (mediumblob) that usually look as ie.:

```
<div align=&quot;center&quot;><span style=&quot;color: rgb(0, 0, 205); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 18pt;&quot;>Lamps Osram H7 Halogen.</span></div><div align=&quot;center&quot;><span style=&quot;color: rgb(0, 0, 205); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 18pt;&quot;>12 Volts - 55 Wats.</span></div>
```

The form have your enctype="multipart/form-data" and the html is edited with InnovaStudio WYSIWYG editor.
When I use Mozilla, Chrome, Ie explorer 11, the form is submitted, and the values stored in database, but when I use IE Edge (windows 10) the proccess abort and display a white screen with the number simbol (#). Removing the color format (ie: color: rgb(0, 0, 205);) the form is submitted, and the values stored in database.

I execute a php mysql error tester script and no query error is present.
Once again I try in IE Edge with another editor that send color as name colors (red, green, yellow, etc.) and the form is submitted, and the values stored in database.
I can only conclude the problem is due to the rgb colors.
Do you have any suggestions or possible solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: You said that if you use other editor then it works. So try to use that method to pass the RGB colors. It is possible that MS Edge only works with that method and with other method it generates an error. also try to check the console in developer tools to check if it shows any error when it shows the white screen with #.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your cooperation.
No error is showed at page code when appear the white screen with #.

I have tried to replace the color names with the rgb codes, but these are sent in hexadecimal format, and the form submitted without errors.
I have used for the test the rich content editor developed by Mozilla.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

I do not know if the format that is sent is inherent to the Agents or comes from the java part of the editors.

I have not been able to find, either in the original editor (InnovaStudio), or the proofs test editor(Mozilla rich content), code for replacement of the color system, only arrays of hex or name colors.

Another curious circumstance with the original editor, is that once the html has been saved in the database without color format, then there are no problems to modify it to text with color in IE Edge and the inserted colors are rgb.

I will continue to do some tests, and if I find any definition of the problem, I will publish it.
Thanks again.